# How to use back-tick in JSON string in JScript

Tags: json, string, jscript

I would like to use back-tick in JSON string to have my values on different lines.....

How do I do that ?

ex:

I want this:

```
var sJsonStridsng = "{"A", "B","numb": { "C", "D"} }";
```

to look like this:

```
var sJsonStridsng = "{
                   "A",
                   "B",
                   "numb": { "C",
                             "D"
                           }
                    }";
```

Comment: You're asking two different questions here. I suggest moving the second to a completely new post.

Comment: What do you mean by "back-tick"? Do you mean this `\`` character?

Comment: @Nick anything that makes me write them on different lines in JSCRIPT. Thank you for the improvements.